# How to query the initial "Remaining work"

Tags: azure-devops

1. I'm trying to query/summarize the total amount of initial "Remaining work" per person per iteration in azure DevOps. In other words, I want to see the sum of the first initially entered "Remaining work" of all the tasks within an iteration per person.
2. Because you can change the "Remaining work" I can't see the initial amount of hours of a task, specialy if the task is put on "done" (then it automatically becomes 0). I can manually see the initial "Remaining work" per task in the history part but I can't find a way to put this in a query.

Would be great if someone knows a solution to this.

Thx

Tshy

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved in Query with web UI. You may need Rest api to first get history and then filter its remaining work. Does this approach is suitable for you?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check with 1 of our BI people

Comment: Just want to check whether Shamrai's answer could help you? If yes, please [mark that reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder. If not, feel free to leave comment below, thus we can continue to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have 2 ways and they are not easy:

1. Use Power Bi to create report and calculate your "Remaining work": [Connect to Analytics with Power BI Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops)
2. Add the "Original estimate" field to the task work item type ([Customize a project using an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops)). Then update it with first value of the "Remaining work" field through the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1): Query work items without value in "Original estimate" and with value in "Remaining work" ([Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)) -> Update "Original estimate"([Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1))

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check with 1 of ou BI people